# How to conditionally supply constructor arguments with StructureMap?

Tags: c#, .net, ioc-container, structuremap

I would like to conditionally supply a constructor argument to StructureMap based on the parent type.
I am trying to achieve this with the code below.

The concrete type ProcessorSettings is a constructor argument to both TypeOne and TypeTwo. 
ProcessorSettings's constructor takes one int parameter named "frequency".

When I try this I get a StructureMap error **StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily** . There is no more information in the error message.

```cs
x.ForConcreteType<ProcessorSettings>()
    .Configure.Ctor<int>("frequency")
    .Is(condition => condition.Conditional(y =>
    {
        y.If(t => t.ParentType == typeof(TypeOne))
            .ThenIt.Is.IsThis(intVal1);

        y.If(t => t.ParentType == typeof(TypeTwo))
            .ThenIt.Is.IsThis(intVal2);
    }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using named instances instead of the conditional. If you have many variations, you can create a [Convention](http://www.theabsentmindedcoder.com/2010/05/structure-map-26-using-conventions.html) to reduce duplication.

```
x.For<ProcessorSettings>().Add<ProcessorSettings>().Ctor<int>("frequency")
    .Is(intVal1).Named("ProcessorSetting1");
x.For<ProcessorSettings>().Add<ProcessorSettings>().Ctor<int>("frequency")
    .Is(intVal2).Named("ProcessorSetting2");
x.For<IType>().Add<TypeOne>().Ctor<ProcessorSettings>()
    .Named("ProcessorSetting1");
x.For<IType>().Add<TypeTwo>().Ctor<ProcessorSettings>()
    .Named("ProcessorSetting2");
```